# How to use application indicator for KDE application?

Tags: indicator, kde, application-development, gtk, ayatana

How can I use libappindicator to create an application indicator for a KDE app in C++ without using GTK? The example shown [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Porting%20Guide%20for%20Applications) uses GTK to create the menu. Is this necessary? Is there a KDE application somewhere that uses an application indicator that I can check out?

(I wanted to tag this question with appindicator and libappindicator, but I don't have enough "reputation" to do that.)

Comment: it's a spec, so I'm guessing there must be a KDE implementation/examples somewhere. I have used a few applications for kde that utilize the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Application indicators are based on KStatusNotifierItem.

I'm not too familiar with it but [here's a tutorial](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/PortToKStatusNotifierItem) on how to get started. That's all you really need to get it to work, the app icon and it's menus should then render properly regardless of which desktop it's in.